# How can I avoid AmbiguousMatchException with duplicate controller names

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project that is used across multiple solutions that contains a controller with views that are commonly used. We also have a web that is the parent application for this project and we are converting the web to use the project rather than defining it's own version of the view so that when we update the project we don't have to also update the web.

The problem I am running into is the web contains a controller named "PlaceholderController" and the project also contains "PlaceholderController" so when running the web and hitting the Placeholder controller I get an AmbiguousMatchException.

I am unable to rename either of these controllers, updating the controller name for the project would require touching many solutions while updating the controller name in the web would require us to update a large amount of URLs as well.

Here is an example of the solution structure

```
Solution 'PlaceholderEngine'
    -PlaceholderEngine.csproj (Web)
        -Views
            -Home
            -Placeholder
                -ExampleView1.cshtml
             ...
            -More
        -Controllers
            -HomeController.cs
            -PlaceholderController.cs
            ...
            -MoreController.cs
    -PlaceholderModule.csproj (Project included in solution)
        -Views
            -Placeholder
                -ExampleView2.cshtml
        -PlaceholderController.cs (unrelated to PlaceholderController in the PlaceHolderEngine (Web) project)
```

here is an example of another solution using the same PlaceHolderModuler project

```
Solution 'OtherWeb'
    -OtherWeb.UI.csproj
    -OtherWeb.Domain.csproj
    -PlaceholderModule.csproj
```

Currently to configure the controller with the web projects we use an extension method for IMVCBuilder that is called in Startup.cs

*Extension Method*

```
...
public static IMvcBuilder ConfigurePlaceholderModule(this IMVCBuilder builder){
    var assembly = typeof(PlaceholderController).Assembly;
    return builder.AddApplicationPart(assembly)
        .AddControllersAsServices()
        .AddRazorOptions(o=>
            o.FileProviders.Add(new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(assembly)));
}
...
```

*Startup.cs ConfigureServices*

```
...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
        ...
        services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
        .ConfigurePlaceholderModule();
        ...
    }
...
```

This set up works for any other project we have but I am having a difficult time figuring out how to avoid the AmbiguousMatchException caused by configuring the PlaceholderModule in the PlaceholderEngine web. Is there a way to route the PlaceholderModule's PlaceholderController differently from PlaceholderEngine's PlaceholderController within Startup.cs? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: consider using areas

Comment: @DanielA.White Would it be possible to put the PlaceholderModule's PlaceholderController in an area for only this one web? Or would I have to use the [Area("SomeArea")] notation above the controller declaration which would put it in an area for all usages?

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to solve this issue. I did figure out that for me the Index Action in PlaceholderModule's PlaceholderController was garbage and unused. I removed that Action and it worked fine. If neither of the controllers share an Action name you will not run into this issue.